# How to use Django in a Python script?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use Django in a python script?

I think I saw something about it in the past, but I can't find any reference to it now. So, basically, I want to build a python script and access Django ORM.

Thanks for any help

Comment: That is normally done through a *management command*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Hi. I'm aware of management commands, but I really want to run a python script this time. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, 'root directory of my project')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
import django
django.setup()
from myapp.models import MyModel

# now you can access MyModel objects just as if you were in a django view
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Somehow I was not finding it. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import django
    django.setup()
```

[More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)