# How to use django orm in not django-project?

Tags: python, django

I have a project with structure like that:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── orm
│   │       ├── app_1
│   │       ├── app_2
│   │       ├── ...
│   │       └── orm
│   │           ├── ...
│   │           └── settings.py
│   └── ...
├── ...
└── main.py
```

I want use django orm in my project but i want to have simple way to change Django ORM to any other ORM. Accordingly that i want isolate django project inside my main project.

I have some class `app.data...DataController` which use Models in any cases. And code in `main.py` use `DataController` to get or load data from DB, other code works already with data but not with Models directly.

To achieve this I wrote this code in `app.data.__init__.py`:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.data.orm.orm.settings")

import django

from django.conf import settings

django.setup()
```

Also if i paste that code anywhere else, in `main.py` for example, that's does not working, django says `ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS`.

And then in `settings.py` i was change dotted pathes to apps like that `'app_1'` -> `'app.data.orm.app_1'`. But for now i can't use django-commands from `manage.py` not from project root directory nor from `app/data/orm`. First, project root directory not in sys.path, second,  if i add it i've get `RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant` exception.

Is there a way to make what i want or what i'm missing?

---

upd.

Ok, I made it work as I described at the beginning, but it looks awful - I moved `manage.py` to the project root, the code with`django.setup ()`lies somewhere in the middle of the project, I had to edit it`manage.py` thus `os.environ.setdefault ('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.data.orm.orm.settings')`.

Is there any more beautiful way to organize a project where you need to use third-party Django ORM?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59416788/494134

Comment: Exactly that i'm trying, but it's not working in my case.

Comment: When you run Django from main.py, every dotted path is **relative** to the location of main.py. So that makes it really tricky because in a Django project normally all dotted paths are relative to **manage.py**. The error `populate() isn't reentrant` means you're calling django.setup() twice somehow, e.g. if you do it in an `__init__.py` file and in `main.py`

Comment: i solve problem with dotted path by moving `manage.py` to root of my project, It works for now, so i bind django project to non-django project.
In general my solution is bad, how i think.